# Uncaught TypeError: Object function Document() { [native code] } has no method 'apply'

Tags: jquery

I've written a very basic slideshow using a bit of jquery. It simply shows a new slide every 5 seconds.

```
function next_slide() {
    var banners = jQuery('.banner-block img');
    var current_b = banners.filter(':visible');
    if (!current_b) {
        current_b = banners.first();
    }
    if (current_b.attr('src') === banners.last().attr('src')) {
        banners.first().addClass('current').fadeIn(1000);
    } else {
        current_b.next().addClass('current').fadeIn(1000);
    }
    current_b.removeClass('current').fadeOut(1000);
}
jQuery(Document).ready(function () {
    setInterval('next_slide()', 5000);
});
```

This works in FF and Safari, but throws the error (see title) in Chrome. I've googled and validated my code, but I can't see what is wrong with my code.

Comment: `Document` has a lowercase `'d'`, not uppercase.  `jQuery(document).ready(function () {`

Comment: P.S. Don't *ever* pass strings to `setInterval`!  That uses `eval`!  Don't use `eval`.  Pass a function: `setInterval(next_slide, 5000);`.

Comment: Note that your `if (!current_b) {...` condition will never be true because `current_b` will always be an object and objects are truthy.

Comment: @nnnnnn: It's actually a jQuery object.  So, to fix it, it should be `if (!current_b.length) {`

Comment: It's a wood for the trees moment, thanks guys. I will certainly fix the !current bit as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as @RocketHazmat has mentioned in the comments..

You want to refer to the DOM object `document`.  The `{ native code }` piece would explain why you are receiving an error in other browsers, and correct behavior in different ones. Some browsers may have a built-in class named Document() that they use to refer to the active document.. but i'm not sure.

Change your statement to

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {...})
```

lower case that `D` to use the DOM object like you want to.

Comment: `Document` is the parent of the `document` object.  `document instanceof Document` is `true` :-)  For fun, try messing with `Document.prototype` :-P

Comment: [Mozilla Document Class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document) , [Safari Document Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/DocumentAdditionsReference/DocumentAdditions/DocumentAdditions.html)